# How to create an object from ClassPathXmlApplicationContext class?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I got an error in my spring project when i try to execute. It is my first spring project. Could you please help me to skip this error? My codes are as follows.

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="user" class="com.beans.demo.User">
        <constructor-arg name="id" value="1"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg name="name" value="Smith"></constructor-arg>
        <property name="emp" ref="emp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="emp" class="com.beans.demo.Employee">
       <property name="emp_id" value="11"></property>
       <property name="emp_name" value="Martin"></property>
       <property name="all_employer">
           <list>
               <value>Google</value>
               <value>Facebook</value>
               <value>Microsoft</value>
           </list>
       </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

BeansDemo.java

```
package com.beans.demo;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class BeansDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/beans/config/beans.xml");
        User user = (User) applicationContext.getBean("user");

        System.out.println("User id and name: " + user.getId() + " and " + user.getName());

        ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)applicationContext).close();
    }
}
```

[image: project structure]

I am getting this error:

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=55724:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/target/classes:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-aspects-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-context-support-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-expression-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-instrument-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-instrument-tomcat-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-oxm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-messaging-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-jdbc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/IntellijProjects/Beans_Demo/lib/spring-test-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/semihkirdinli/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar
>   com.beans.demo.BeansDemo Jul 15, 2019 2:31:24 PM
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@14514713:
>   startup date [Mon Jul 15 14:31:24 EET 2019]; root of context hierarchy
>   Jul 15, 2019 2:31:24 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path
>   resource [com/beans/config/beans.xml] Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from class path resource
>   [com/beans/config/beans.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [com/beans/config/beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not
>   exist     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:515)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     at com.beans.demo.BeansDemo.main(BeansDemo.java:13) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [com/beans/config/beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not
>   exist     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
>     ... 13 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: The exception tells you what is wrong... The file isn't int he location you told it is.

Comment: But, there is a file.

-Beans_Demo
    -.idea
    -lib
    -src
        -main
            -java
                -com.beans
                    -config
                        -beans.xml
                    -demo
                        -BeansDemo
                        -Employee
                        -User
            -resources
        -Beans_Demo.iml
        -pom.xml

Comment: Not according to the error and the error generally isn't wrong. So it must be your setup. If you are following maven conventions `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` the xml file has to be in resources if it is in java it will not be available in the class path (non java files are filtered out by maven).

Comment: There are src/main/java and src/main/resources folder in my structure

Comment: But your XML file is in the java one not in the resources one.

Comment: You can see my project structure in my question when you look again. i updated the question.

Comment: again your XML file is in `src/main/java` NOT in `src/main/resources`... If it is not in `src/main/resources` it will not be available in the calsspath. NON java files are not allowed in `src/main/java` and as such are ignored. With the result that the file will not be found. Looking again you don't even have a `src/main/resources` you have a `src/main/java/resources` if I see your structure.